# Geoserver WFS GetFeature query that matches entire word in string

Tags: geoserver, wfs, getfeature

I am trying to write a WFS getfeature query for some GeoServer JSON data that returns features that match a part of a string only if the entire word matches. The word can be in the start, middle, or end of the string. I started by using `cql_filter`, but am returning records that don't match a whole word.

Say I have two features with the following values for `AddLocID`:

```
id, AddLocID  
1,  216  
2,  216 72216  
3,  72216
```

I want to return features 1 & 2 and not feature 3

Using `cql_filter=AddLocID=216` returns only feature 1 and does not match feature 2

https://bloomington.in.gov/geoserver/publicgis/ows?service=WFS&version=1.0.0&request=GetFeature&typeName=publicgis:HistoricSitesandStructuresSurvey2018&cql_filter=AddLocID=216&outputFormat=application%2Fjson

Using `cql_filter=AddLocID Like 216` returns all 3 features but I only want 1 and 2

https://bloomington.in.gov/geoserver/publicgis/ows?service=WFS&version=1.0.0&request=GetFeature&typeName=publicgis:HistoricSitesandStructuresSurvey2018&cql_filter=AddLocIDlike%27%216%%27&outputFormat=application%2Fjson

How can a write my query so that records 1 and 2 are return that match 216 as a whole word in the string value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`isLike` function](https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/filter/function_reference.html#comparison-functions) which takes a full [Java Rexep](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) for the match. In your case you could use something like:

```
cql_filter=isLike("AddLocID",'.*\b216\b.*')=true
```

so that `\b` matches a word boundary. You may need to experiment with just how many `\` will be required for it to work.

Comment: Here is the url that worked using this approach, Thanks!   
(https://bloomington.in.gov/geoserver/publicgis/ows?service=WFS&version=1.0.0&request=GetFeature&typeName=publicgis:HistoricSitesandStructuresSurvey2018&cql_filter=isLike(AddLocID,'.*\b17216\b.*')=true&outputFormat=application%2Fjson)